# How to change the width of a div of another file using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm loading a fonts.php file like this to students.php.

```
$("#details").load('fonts.php?id=2', function() {
    $("#details").show();
    $(".gallery").css("width", "80%");
});
```

gallery is a div in fonts.php file. I need to chage the width of this div after it loads to the students.php file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see you are changing the width of class `gallery`. What happens when you change it for `#details`?

Comment: You mean change the width of `#details` is it? Here my code for `$(".gallery").css("width", "80%");` is not working. I need to change the with of the `.gallery` from the students.php file. Please help.

Comment: What if you try to inspect the element? Does it show that css attribute was applied?

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing was changed. It was as previously.

Comment: do not post your comments as ANSWER.